# Google sheet - copy data to another tab based on condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to create a script or a macro that can basically copy data from particular columns in sheet 1 to sheet 2 when you select an item from a drop-down in a column in sheet1.

I have a google sheet that has patient info and their medical procedure in tab 1, 15 columns. When a user select "Completed" from the dropdown menu in column 6, I want the data in the first 4 columns of that row to be copied in tab 2.
Is there a plugin available or do I need to write a script?

Answer (score 1):

Try the the [moveRowsFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/39992635?msgid=40432488) script. Follow the instructions in the script to set the parameters and install it in your spreadsheet.

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).